# Prove $a_n^k$ convergence by induction

Tags: calculus

Question: 
$a_n \to L, 0 \le a_n, 0 \le L $
prove that $\forall k \in \Bbb N : a_n^k \to L^k$

What I did:
From the limit definition: $\lvert a_n-L \rvert <\varepsilon$.
Obviously it has to do with induction so from what is given I have correctness of $k=1$ for sure. I assumed correctness for $k-1$, and when I got to prove it for $k$, I used this formula $x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+...+y^{k-1}$) . So using it on $x=a_n$ and $y=L$ I got to the fact that $a_n^k-L^k<\varepsilon \cdot (x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+...+y^{k-1})$, the part in parenthesis is positive so I don't know how I can put a bound to it and make this whole thing become smaller than $\varepsilon$. Thought maybe somehow modify it to use the induction assumption for $k-1$, but don't know how to.

Comment: @user1685524 Can you use the property that says that if $\lim (x_n), \lim (y_n)$ exist (and are finite), then $\lim (x_ny_n)=\lim (x_n)\lim (y_n)$?

Comment: no. We're allowed to use only the limit definition and the squeeze theorem. (Haven't got to arithmetic yet)

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n^k-L^k=(a_n-L)\left(a_n^{k-1}+a_n^{k-2}L+\ldots+aL^{k-2}+L^{k-1}\right)$$

But by the inductive hypothesis you know that

$$a_n^{k-j}L^{j-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}L^{k-j}L^{j-1}=L^{k-1}\;,\;\text{ so }\ldots$$

Comment: So do I get that the parenthesis equals $a_n^{k-1}+(k-1)  * L^{k-1}$ ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more... I can't seem to get it yet. Thanks